# Thunderbird: assign shortcut to text style

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, thunderbird

Is there a way to map custom keyboard shortcuts to text styles used while composing a message?

I need it, for example, for the Code style applied often to parts of message body:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible to achieve directly, but you can do it via extension:

1. Install the [tbkeys-lite](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/tbkeys-lite/) extension.
2. Go to Settings -> Themes and Extensions -> Extensions, open the `tbkeys-lite` configuration.
3. Write the configuration you want to the `Compose key bindings` field and click the `Save settings` button.

For example, to assign the `Ctrl+Shift+X` shortcut to the `code` style, add the following content:

```
{
    "ctrl+shift+x": "cmd:cmd_code"
}
```

In order to get more command codes, please read the [official documentation](https://github.com/wshanks/tbkeys#customizing-key-bindings) or check the referenced [wiki page](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Keyconfig_extension:_Thunderbird) and look at the HTML section.